# Get Refresh Time and Date on Winforms Label

Tags: c#, winforms

My goal is to have a C# Winforms label that shows the last date/time the label was refreshed.

I have a TIMER_Tick event that refreshes after 1000 ms and is refreshing a toolstrip_button that fetches all the data.

I need to get a label2 that will display the last refresh time so that I can compare my data with the time on the label in attempt to troubleshoot an issue. I tried using label2.Text = this.DateTime.Now but I am not sure if that is something that continuously changes, or if it is the TIMER refreshing it.

And ideas on how I can get a label that shows me just when the last refresh happened?

Comment: `DateTime.Now` is always set to the current date and time. If you want to keep track of when the timer refreshes, just have a `DateTime` variable somewhere and set it to `DateTime.Now` within the tick event.

Comment: `label2.Text = this.DateTime.Now;` will set the label to the current time, at that point in time. It will not update or change the label continuously, so only call that line whenever you actually read NEW DATA from somewhere. In your Tick event code, can you differentiate if the data just read is different from the previously fetched data?

Comment: That's perfect, I have it updating every time data is fetched, which is every 1 second at the moment. The issue I'm having is with the data being updated in the app. Although the TIMER is changing every second, I'm watching the database while running my app and my app it is skipping some data points.  The data and the label are within a toolstrip_button1 that fetches the data. I get about one data point per 6 seconds so that shouldn't be the issue either. Let me know if you have any tips/suggestions.

Comment: We'd have to see some CODE to figure out what the issue is.

Comment: I'll open a new ticket. Thanks.